# How do I get the path of a binary in c#?

Tags: c#

For some reporting purposes I'm trying to get the location of a certain binary.

I was doing this, and it was working, but I'm now getting a NullReferenceException when I try to get testProc.MainModule.FileName; and I think it may be that the program is closing before I'm able to grab it. Is there any better way to do this?

```
ProcessStartInfo testPSI = new ProcessStartInfo(RunOptions.TestBinary);
testPSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
testPSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
testPSI.UseShellExecute = false;
Process testProc = new Process();
testProc.StartInfo = testPSI;   
testProc.Start();
ret = testProc.MainModule.FileName;
testProc.Kill();
if (ret != null)
    return ret;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use the path you already have.

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you're creating the process yourself (with `RunOptions.TestBinary`), so you should already know the path. You can get the full path to the executable with `Path.GetFullPath(RunOptions.TestBinary)`, or if the binary is on the `PATH`, you can manually examine each directory to determine where the binary is being executed from.

**Option 2:** Use C#'s [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) libraries:

If there are differences in bitness (32-bit/64-bit) between the test host process and the process being executed, then enumerating modules and getting the file name will not work. You can use WMI to get around this limitation, however.

Add a reference to `System.Management` and try the following (warning: no error handling):

```
static string GetImagePath(int processId)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID='{0}'", processId);
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
    ManagementObject process = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
    return (string)process["ExecutablePath"];
}
```

**Option 3:** Add synchronization to the target process:

If this really is a timing issue (i.e. the monitored process is dying before the test process can examine it), then you can add some synchronization (e.g. named mutex) between the two processes. If you really want to dig deep, you can use [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture process start events (see below).

**Option 4:** Use [the TraceEvent .NET library](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/99984) to capture process start events.

Vance Morrison (who wrote the TraceEvent library) has [an in-depth article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/03/09/using-traceevent-to-mine-information-in-os-registered-etw-providers.aspx) on how to capture process start events. This solution does require pulling in a bunch of dependencies, but since it uses ETW, there would not be a timing issue (even if the process dies quickly, the process start event is still fired). This is by far the most complex solution.